# Why my shaders are not loading - Unity WebGL (Universal Render Pipeline/Lit)

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

I try to export my game under WebGL but all my shaders do not load when I compile my Unity project.

- Unity version: 2020.1.8f1
- Render Pipeline: UniversalRP-HighQuality

[image: What i need] Expected final rendering and what I have when I compile for PC

[image: What I have] What I have  when I compile for WebGL

[image: My mesh renderer] My mesh renderer

[image: My shader] My shader

Same thing for all my Mesh with Shader.

Ask me if you need to know anything else. I can share my project settings if it can help.

Waiting for an answer.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you specifically add the shader to the build or leave it to unity to work out?

Comment: I leave it to Unity. I don't know where to add a material shader (can you tell me?). I edit my post with a screen of graphics settings if it can help

Comment: Um. Its hard not to sound sarcastic but the always include shaders bit on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the shader to the graphics settings but an error occurs during compilation. the shader seems too heavy. To pass the bug I abandoned this shader and I use the Sprites/Default or URP/Unlit material
[image]